# Overlapping with geom_text, how to avoid?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, text, overlap

I'm trying to do a strange plot..
Here is a sample of my data:

```
structure(list(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 
22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 
26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 
27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 
31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 
31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 
34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 
35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 
36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 
36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 
37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 
38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 
38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 
38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 
39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 
39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 
41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 
41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 
42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 
42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 
42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 
42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 
43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 
43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 
43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 
44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 
45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 
45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 
46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 47, 49, 49, 
49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 
49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 
49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 
49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 
49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 
49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 
52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 
52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 53, 53, 53, 
53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 
53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 
53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 
53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 
53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 
54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 
54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 
55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 
55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 56, 56, 56, 
56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 
56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 
57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 
57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 
57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 
57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 
58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 
58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 
59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 
59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 
59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 
59, 59, 59, 59, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 
60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 
60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 
60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60), id_rev = c(999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 
994, 988, 987, 986, 985, 984, 999, 998, 997, 996, 983, 982, 981, 
980, 979, 978, 977, 960, 959, 958, 957, 956, 955, 954, 953, 952, 
999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 991, 990, 989, 988, 987, 
986, 985, 984, 983, 982, 981, 980, 979, 978, 977, 976, 975, 974, 
973, 972, 971, 970, 969, 968, 967, 966, 965, 964, 963, 962, 961, 
960, 959, 958, 957, 956, 955, 954, 953, 952, 951, 950, 949, 948, 
947, 946, 945, 944, 940, 939, 938, 937, 936, 935, 934, 994, 993, 
992, 991, 990, 989, 988, 979, 978, 977, 976, 975, 974, 973, 972, 
971, 970, 969, 968, 967, 966, 965, 964, 963, 962, 961, 960, 959, 
958, 957, 956, 955, 954, 953, 952, 951, 950, 949, 948, 947, 946, 
999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 
991, 990, 989, 988, 987, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 
991, 990, 989, 988, 987, 986, 982, 981, 980, 979, 978, 977, 976, 
975, 974, 973, 972, 971, 970, 969, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 
992, 991, 990, 989, 988, 987, 986, 985, 990, 989, 988, 987, 986, 
985, 984, 983, 986, 985, 984, 983, 982, 981, 960, 959, 958, 957, 
956, 955, 954, 953, 947, 946, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 
983, 982, 981, 980, 979, 978, 977, 976, 975, 974, 973, 972, 971, 
959, 958, 957, 983, 982, 981, 980, 979, 978, 971, 970, 969, 968, 
967, 966, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 990, 989, 988, 987, 986, 985, 
967, 966, 965, 964, 950, 949, 948, 947, 946, 945, 944, 943, 942, 
941, 940, 939, 938, 986, 985, 984, 983, 982, 981, 982, 981, 980, 
979, 978, 973, 972, 971, 970, 969, 968, 950, 949, 948, 947, 946, 
945, 966, 965, 964, 963, 962, 961, 960, 959, 986, 985, 984, 983, 
982, 981, 980, 979, 978, 977, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 
992, 991, 990, 989, 988, 987, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 
992, 949, 948, 947, 946, 945, 944, 943, 981, 980, 979, 978, 977, 
976, 975, 974, 973, 972, 971, 970, 969, 968, 967, 966, 965, 964, 
990, 989, 988, 987, 986, 985, 984, 983, 970, 969, 968, 967, 966, 
972, 971, 970, 969, 968, 967, 966, 965, 964, 963, 962, 961, 960, 
948, 947, 946, 945, 944, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 967, 966, 
965, 964, 963, 962, 961, 960, 959, 958, 957, 956, 955, 954, 999, 
998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 985, 984, 983, 982, 981, 980, 979, 
978, 977, 976, 975, 974, 973, 972, 971, 970, 969, 968, 967, 966, 
965, 964, 966, 965, 964, 963, 962, 961, 960, 959, 958, 957, 956, 
955, 954, 986, 985, 984, 983, 982, 981, 980, 979, 973, 972, 971, 
970, 946, 945, 944, 943, 942, 941, 940, 939, 938, 993, 992, 991, 
990, 989, 988, 987, 986, 985, 984, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 
983, 982, 981, 980, 979, 978, 977, 976, 975, 974, 973, 972, 971, 
970, 969, 968, 967, 966, 965, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 
992, 984, 983, 982, 981, 980, 979, 978, 977, 958, 957, 956, 955, 
954, 953, 952, 951, 950, 971, 970, 969, 968, 967, 966, 965, 964, 
963, 962, 961, 960, 959, 958, 957, 956, 955, 954, 953, 952, 951, 
999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 972, 971, 970, 969, 968, 967, 
966, 965, 964, 963, 962, 961, 960, 959, 958, 957, 956, 955, 954, 
953, 952, 951, 950, 949, 948, 947, 946, 945, 944, 943, 942, 941, 
940, 939, 938, 937, 936, 935, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 
992, 991, 990, 989, 988, 987, 986, 985, 984, 983, 982, 981, 980, 
979, 978, 977, 976, 975, 974, 973, 972, 971, 970, 969, 968, 967, 
966, 965, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 991, 990, 989, 
988, 987, 986, 985, 984, 983, 982, 981, 980, 979, 978, 977, 976, 
975, 974, 931, 930, 929, 928, 927, 926, 925, 924, 923, 999, 998, 
997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 991, 990, 989, 988, 987, 986, 985, 
976, 975, 974, 973, 972, 971, 970, 969, 968, 967, 966, 965, 964, 
963, 962, 961, 960, 959, 958, 957, 956, 955, 954, 953, 952, 999, 
998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 991, 990, 989, 978, 977, 976, 
975, 974, 973, 972, 971, 970, 969, 968, 967, 966, 965, 964, 963, 
962, 961, 960, 959, 958, 957, 956, 955, 954, 953, 952, 951, 950, 
949, 948, 947, 946, 945, 944, 943, 942, 941, 940, 939, 938, 937, 
936, 935, 934, 933, 932, 931, 930, 929, 994, 993, 992, 991, 990, 
989, 988, 987, 986, 985, 984, 983, 982, 981, 980, 979, 978, 977, 
976, 975, 974, 973, 972, 971, 970, 969, 968, 967, 966, 965, 964, 
963, 962, 961, 960, 959, 958, 957, 956, 955, 954, 953, 952, 951, 
950, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 991, 990, 989, 988, 
987, 986, 985, 984, 983, 982, 981, 980, 979, 978, 977, 976, 999, 
998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 991, 970, 969, 968, 967, 966, 
965, 964, 963, 962, 961, 960, 959, 958, 957, 956, 955, 954, 953, 
999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 991, 990, 989, 988, 987, 
986, 985, 984, 983, 982, 981, 980, 979, 999, 998, 997, 999, 998, 
997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 991, 990, 989, 988, 987, 986, 985, 
984, 983, 982, 981, 980, 979, 978, 977, 976, 975, 974, 973, 972, 
971, 970, 969, 968, 967, 966, 965, 964, 963, 962, 961, 960, 959, 
958, 957, 956, 955, 954, 953, 952, 951, 950, 949, 948, 947, 946, 
945, 944, 943, 942, 941, 940, 939, 938, 937, 936, 935, 934, 933, 
932, 931, 930, 929, 928, 927, 926, 925, 924, 923, 922, 921, 920, 
919, 918, 917, 916, 915, 914, 913, 912, 911, 910, 909, 908, 999, 
998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 991, 990, 989, 988, 987, 986, 
985, 984, 983, 982, 981, 980, 979, 978, 977, 976, 975, 974, 973, 
972, 971, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 991, 990, 989, 
988, 987, 986, 985, 984, 983, 982, 981, 980, 979, 978, 977, 976, 
975, 974, 973, 972, 971, 970, 969, 968, 967, 966, 965, 964, 963, 
962, 954, 953, 952, 951, 950, 949, 948, 947, 946, 945, 944, 943, 
942, 941, 940, 939, 938, 937, 936, 935, 934, 933, 932, 999, 998, 
997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 991, 990, 989, 988, 987, 986, 985, 
984, 983, 982, 981, 980, 979, 978, 977, 976, 975, 974, 973, 972, 
971, 970, 969, 968, 967, 966, 965, 964, 963, 962, 961, 960, 959, 
999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 991, 990, 989, 988, 987, 
986, 985, 984, 983, 982, 981, 980, 979, 978, 977, 976, 975, 958, 
957, 956, 955, 954, 953, 952, 951, 950, 949, 948, 947, 946, 945, 
944, 943, 942, 941, 940, 939, 938, 937, 936, 935, 934, 933, 932, 
931, 930, 929, 928, 927, 926, 925, 924, 923, 922, 921, 920, 919, 
918, 917, 916, 915, 914, 913, 912, 911, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 
994, 993, 992, 991, 990, 989, 988, 987, 986, 985, 984, 983, 982, 
981, 980, 979, 978, 977, 976, 975, 974, 973, 972, 999, 998, 997, 
996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 991, 990, 989, 988, 982, 981, 980, 979, 
978, 977, 976, 975, 974, 973, 972, 971, 970, 969, 968, 967, 966, 
965, 964, 963, 962, 961, 960, 942, 941, 940, 939, 938, 937, 936, 
935, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 991, 990, 989, 988, 
987, 986, 985, 984, 983, 982, 973, 972, 971, 970, 969, 968, 967, 
966, 981, 980, 979, 978, 977, 976, 975, 974, 973, 972, 971, 970, 
969, 968, 967, 966, 965, 964, 963, 962, 961, 960, 959, 958, 957, 
956, 955, 954, 953, 952, 951, 950, 949, 948, 947, 946, 945, 944, 
943, 942, 941, 940, 939, 938, 937, 936, 935, 934, 933, 932, 931, 
930, 929, 928, 927, 926, 925, 924, 923, 922, 921, 920, 919, 918, 
917, 916, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 979, 978, 977, 976, 975, 
974, 948, 947, 946, 945, 944, 943, 942, 941, 940, 939, 938, 937, 
936, 935, 934, 933, 932, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 
991, 990, 989, 988, 987, 986, 985, 984, 983, 982, 981, 980, 979, 
978, 977, 976, 975, 974, 973, 964, 963, 962, 961, 960, 959, 958, 
957, 956, 955, 954, 953, 952, 951, 950, 949, 948, 947, 946, 945, 
944, 943, 942, 941, 940, 939, 938, 937, 936, 935, 934, 933, 932, 
931, 930, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 991, 990, 989, 
988, 987, 986, 985, 984, 983, 974, 973, 972, 971, 970, 969, 968, 
967, 966, 965, 964, 963, 962, 961, 960, 959, 958, 957, 956, 955, 
954, 953, 952, 951, 950, 949, 948, 947, 946, 945, 944, 943, 942, 
941), word_split = c("a", "o", "m", "a", "m", "e", "j", "u", 
"b", "a", "l", "j", "i", "l", "l", "f", "u", "k", "a", "e", "r", 
"i", "g", "e", "n", "e", "r", "a", "t", "e", "d", "b", "y", "a", 
"b", "c", "a", "m", "b", "e", "r", "l", "i", "t", "c", "o", "n", 
"v", "e", "r", "t", "e", "r", "h", "t", "t", "p", "w", "w", "w", 
".", "p", "r", "o", "c", "e", "s", "s", "t", "e", "x", "t", ".", 
"c", "o", "m", "a", "b", "c", "l", "i", "t", ".", "h", "t", "m", 
"l", "m", "a", "r", "t", "i", "n", "a", "k", "o", "m", "a", "t", 
"s", "u", "t", "a", "m", "a", "r", "u", "h", "a", "r", "s", "h", 
"a", "w", "l", "i", "t", "t", "l", "e", "p", "e", "o", "p", "l", 
"e", "c", "r", "i", "s", "a", "l", "i", "d", "e", "a", "y", "u", 
"m", "i", "p", "a", "t", "t", "y", "m", "a", "r", "z", "i", "a", 
"n", "o", "c", "a", "x", "t", "o", "n", "s", "a", "k", "i", "g", 
"a", "k", "e", "l", "u", "n", "a", "p", "r", "o", "f", "e", "s", 
"s", "o", "r", "e", "g", "r", "o", "c", "c", "o", "t", "e", "l", 
"e", "f", "o", "n", "o", "u", "s", "h", "i", "k", "a", "w", "a", 
"d", "o", "r", "c", "a", "s", "g", "r", "o", "c", "c", "a", "r", 
"e", "u", "h", "g", "e", "m", "e", "l", "l", "i", "m", "i", "r", 
"i", "a", "m", "m", "a", "h", "m", "o", "u", "d", "u", "h", "m", 
"v", "o", "r", "r", "e", "i", "m", "i", "l", "a", "n", "o", "s", 
"e", "t", "t", "a", "f", "o", "s", "t", "e", "r", "l", "u", "n", 
"e", "m", "a", "r", "z", "i", "a", "n", "i", "b", "o", "o", "n", 
"e", "t", "a", "m", "a", "k", "i", "l", "a", "r", "r", "y", "f", 
"u", "k", "a", "d", "a", "d", "’", "a", "r", "i", "a", "c", "o", 
"m", "u", "n", "i", "t", "à", "m", "a", "t", "e", "m", "a", "t", 
"i", "c", "a", "g", "r", "o", "c", "c", "a", "t", "o", "g", "a", 
"t", "t", "i", "b", "e", "r", "q", "u", "i", "s", "t", "e", "b", 
"i", "s", "u", "n", "o", "a", "m", "i", "c", "a", "t", "s", "u", 
"b", "a", "s", "a", "r", "a", "s", "a", "t", "o", "m", "a", "r", 
"z", "i", "a", "n", "a", "t", "o", "k", "y", "o", "p", "r", "o", 
"f", "e", "s", "s", "o", "r", "n", "i", "n", "a", "t", "a", "s", 
"s", "ì", "l", "a", "u", "r", "i", "e", "d", "’", "u", "n", "a", 
"l", "'", "a", "u", "t", "i", "s", "t", "a", "r", "o", "b", "e", 
"r", "t", "a", "d", "i", "g", "b", "y", "s", "t", "i", "n", "k", 
"y", "t", "a", "n", "g", "e", "n", "z", "i", "a", "l", "e", "p", 
"i", "e", "n", "e", "z", "z", "a", "c", "a", "l", "m", "a", "n", 
"h", "k", "r", "u", "o", "l", "o", "t", "a", "x", "i", "j", "e", 
"a", "n", "n", "e", "t", "t", "e", "1", "q", "8", "4", "w", "e", 
"r", "n", "e", "r", "k", "a", "w", "a", "n", "a", "t", "e", "s", 
"t", "i", "m", "o", "n", "i", "o", "s", "c", "r", "i", "t", "t", 
"o", "r", "i", "d", "a", "u", "g", "h", "t", "e", "r", "p", "a", 
"t", "r", "i", "c", "i", "a", "s", "c", "r", "i", "t", "t", "o", 
"r", "e", "t", "r", "o", "m", "p", "f", "o", "s", "t", "e", "r", 
"i", "t", "i", "s", "m", "o", "r", "f", "i", "a", "s", "i", "c", 
"c", "o", "m", "e", "v", "a", "l", "e", "n", "t", "i", "n", "e", 
"j", "a", "n", "á", "c", "e", "k", "l", "i", "c", "e", "o", "r", 
"i", "s", "c", "r", "i", "t", "t", "u", "r", "a", "b", "l", "a", 
"n", "c", "a", "y", "e", "n", "g", "i", "a", "p", "p", "o", "n", 
"e", "s", "e", "v", "i", "a", "g", "g", "i", "o", "s", "e", "n", 
"t", "o", "r", "i", "c", "e", "v", "i", "t", "o", "r", "e", "l", 
"a", "n", "c", "i", "ò", "s", "h", "i", "n", "j", "u", "k", "u", 
"c", "a", "n", "e", "m", "a", "c", "c", "h", "i", "n", "a", "s", 
"c", "r", "i", "v", "a", "n", "i", "a", "g", "h", "i", "l", "i", 
"a", "c", "h", "i", "y", "a", "s", "u", "d", "a", "c", "h", "a", 
"m", "p", "i", "o", "n", "a", "s", "c", "o", "l", "t", "a", "v", 
"a", "p", "l", "a", "s", "t", "i", "c", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", 
"n", "d", "o", "n", "a", "t", "o", "g", "i", "l", "l", "i", "a", 
"n", "t", "r", "a", "n", "c", "e", "b", "e", "c", "k", "y", "p", 
"r", "e", "p", "a", "r", "a", "t", "o", "r", "i", "a", "l", "e", 
"z", "i", "o", "n", "i", "c", "o", "m", "p", "e", "n", "s", "o", 
"p", "a", "o", "l", "o", "c", "a", "v", "e", "n", "d", "i", "s", 
"h", "p", "a", "i", "w", "o", "n", "s", "k", "i", "m", "o", "n", 
"t", "a", "g", "n", "e", "d", "i", "c", "i", "a", "s", "s", "e", 
"t", "t", "e", "e", "d", "i", "t", "r", "i", "c", "e", "r", "o", 
"m", "p", "i", "g", "h", "i", "a", "c", "c", "i", "o", "c", "e", 
"n", "a", "s", "c", "i", "v", "o", "l", "o", "p", "a", "o", "l", 
"a", "n", "i", "c", "k", "s", "c", "e", "n", "d", "e", "r", "e", 
"t", "e", "l", "e", "f", "o", "n", "a", "t", "a", "a", "d", "a", 
"t", "t", "o", "t", "e", "s", "t", "i", "m", "o", "n", "i", "c", 
"e", "c", "h", "o", "v", "h", "o", "o", "g", "r", "o", "c", "c", 
"a", "v", "a", "l", "a", "r", "k", "i", "n", "s", "i", "n", "f", 
"o", "n", "i", "e", "t", "t", "a", "t", "r", "a", "c", "o", "l", 
"l", "a", "r", "a", "c", "c", "o", "n", "t", "o", "r", "i", "g", 
"u", "a", "r", "d", "o", "q", "u", "e", "s", "t", "'", "u", "o", 
"m", "o", "a", "z", "a", "m", "i", "r", "e", "l", "i", "g", "i", 
"o", "s", "o", "m", "a", "r", "g", "h", "e", "r", "i", "t", "a", 
"a", "n", "t", "o", "n", "e", "l", "l", "a", "b", "o", "a", "r", 
"d", "m", "a", "n", "g", "r", "o", "c", "c", "a", "g", "r", "o", 
"c", "c", "h", "i", "t", "r", "a", "f", "f", "i", "c", "o", "d", 
"o", "l", "c", "e", "m", "e", "n", "t", "e", "d", "o", "t", "a", 
"t", "o", "c", "o", "n", "t", "r", "o", "l", "l", "ò", "y", "a", 
"m", "a", "n", "a", "s", "h", "i", "a", "n", "n", "e", "m", "a", 
"d", "a", "m", "e", "a", "l", "l", "'", "i", "n", "g", "r", "e", 
"s", "s", "o", "a", "l", "l", "i", "e", "s", "a", "m", "p", "a", 
"z", "i", "e", "n", "z", "a", "c", "a", "p", "e", "z", "z", "o", 
"l", "i", "s", "c", "u", "s", "i", "p", "o", "l", "i", "z", "i", 
"o", "t", "t", "i", "d", "i", "v", "a", "n", "o", "s", "a", "h", 
"a", "l", "i", "n", "v", "e", "d", "e", "v", "o", "p", "e", "r", 
"u", "g", "i", "a", "l", "i", "v", "i", "a", "d", "'", "e", "m", 
"e", "r", "g", "e", "n", "z", "a", "c", "a", "m", "i", "c", "e", 
"t", "t", "a", "p", "e", "r", "c", "e", "p", "i", "v", "a", "v", 
"a", "s", "o", "e", "l", "e", "g", "a", "n", "t", "e", "p", "i", 
"s", "t", "o", "l", "e", "w", "o", "r", "d", "p", "r", "o", "c", 
"e", "s", "s", "o", "r", "g", "i", "a", "r", "d", "i", "n", "o", 
"b", "o", "r", "s", "o", "n", "e", "l", "a", "r", "e", "m", "i", 
"w", "i", "l", "l", "i", "e", "c", "u", "s", "p", "i", "d", "e", 
"r", "i", "u", "s", "c", "i", "v", "a", "m", "o", "l", "o", "u", 
"i", "s", "e", "t", "a", "t", "u", "a", "g", "g", "i", "r", "u", 
"t", "h", "d", "r", "a", "t", "t", "i", "g", "i", "u", "l", "i", 
"a", "n", "o", "c", "h", "i", "e", "d", "e", "v", "o", "a", "g", 
"n", "e", "s", "v", "e", "s", "a", "n", "t", "m", "a", "c", "k", 
"e", "n", "z", "i", "e", "h", "o", "n", "e", "y", "m", "o", "t", 
"o", "r", "i", "n", "o", "p", "r", "o", "f", "e", "s", "s", "o", 
"r", "e", "s", "s", "a", "a", "u", "r", "e", "l", "i", "o", "q", 
"u", "i", "m", "a", "n", "d", "i", "s", "s", "e", "t", "t", "m", 
"u", "l", "i", "n", "o", "r", "a", "c", "h", "e", "l", "g", "u", 
"a", "r", "d", "a", "v", "a", "m", "o", "a", "m", "a", "r", "i", 
"g", "o", "p", "o", "t", "e", "v", "a", "m", "o", "p", "a", "r", 
"l", "a", "v", "a", "m", "o", "g", "e", "n", "e", "r", "a", "t", 
"o", "r", "e", "t", "a", "n", "n", "e", "r", "f", "i", "n", "i", 
"s", "c", "i", "l", "a", "b", "r", "a", "d", "l", "e", "y", "k", 
"u", "n", "g", "c", "e", "r", "c", "a", "v", "a", "m", "o", "s", 
"a", "c", "c", "h", "i", "g", "u", "b", "b", "i", "o", "t", "a", 
"m", "b", "a", "t", "e", "r", "r", "e", "s", "t", "r", "i", "s", 
"t", "e", "r", "e", "o", "v", "i", "s", "i", "o", "n", "e", "s", 
"t", "e", "r", "e", "o", "v", "i", "s", "o", "r", "e")), row.names = c(NA, 
-1501L), class = "data.frame")
```

The variabile: word split are letter, letters consitute words (jubal is a word, jill is a word, grocchi is a word etc.)
My goal is to do a plot formatted like this...

```
ggplot()+geom_text(data=DF_TOT, aes(x=x, y=id_rev,label=word_split))
```

[image]

BUT I don't like the result because it is unreadable...due to the overlapping of the letters (e.g. Jill)
I already tried to: reduce the size of letters (with more data letters are too small), paste0 \n at each letter (doesnt work), multiply by two id_rev (doesnt change because the y scale remains the same)

Do you have any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: Data was updated with more data (plot refers to old data but the problem is the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play around `position_stack()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot()+
  geom_text(data=DF_TOT,
            aes(x=x, y=id_rev,label=word_split),
            position = position_stack(0.75),size=3)
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:** In some sense this can be useful:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code 2
DF_TOT %>%
  mutate(word_split=paste0(word_split,'\n ',' ')) %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_text(aes(x=x, y=id_rev,label=word_split),
            position = position_stack(0.5),size=2)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0.5),limits = c(NA,90000))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it does not work with more data...still overlapped :(

Comment: @GiuseppyWasVeryVeryHappy Could you add more data to see the issue?

Comment: data updated in the first question. Thank for your time, very appreciate!

Comment: @GiuseppyWasVeryVeryHappy I have added an update, hope that helps!

Comment: Looks great! Thank you!!

Comment: @GiuseppyWasVeryVeryHappy Amazing, and always a pleasure helping. Let me know if all was clear in last code :)